# Remove commas from lightning:input type="Number"

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i have a markup like below
when i enter numbers in the field like 12345 it comes as '12,345'.
I dont want commas in the number field. the fields functional significance is that its a zipcode field. so it doesnt look good to my client if they see commas in a zipcode field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I would not use lightning:input with type="Number" for the ZipCode instead will prefer using default with type="text" and use regex pattern to validate the format

Here is a sample code

```
<lightning:input pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="number" label="Number" value="12345"/>
```

The above automatically validates that user uses 5 digit ZipCode else it throws an error .

If you are looking for internationalization solution then the below [link](http://html5pattern.com/Postal_Codes) lists all the patterns

Comment: The field type is number in the backend salesforce object. So this means should i convert string to number before i save the data in salesforce?

Comment: I would keep the backend field to be of string datatype as well and write a validation rule to maintain data integrity .The number field helps in aggregation or any sort of numeric calculation while you do not want to do any numeric calculation on zipcode .So to me Zipcode should be a text field both at front and backend .

Comment: @RedDevil - Standard PostalCode fields are test fields not numbers

Comment: Thank you so much Mohith and Eric for taking time to reply.  Maybe i gave a bad example. what if i want to use lightning input type = number without commas. Is that even possible?

Comment: That's a great question .I will see if I get any hint on how to do this .Let's keep the question open

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would hate to use hacky ways to work around limitations of Salesforce, but since there seems to be no easy way to fix this using the formatter options Salesforce provides for `lightning:input`, here's some CSS as a quick fix:

```
input.slds-input {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

The `!important` is important since there's no other way to override inline styling applied by Salesforce's Aura framework.

Edit: This no longer works in the newer versions of Aura framework

Comment: I've tried this out and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used Regex to remove character entered by the users and show only numbers.

Below is the code in Aura

```
Component 
<lightning:input label="PIN/OTP" aura:id="pin" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"  />
Controller 
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var pin = component.find("pin").set("v.value",component.find("pin").get("v.value").replace(/\D/g, ""));
}
```

Below code for LWC

```
html
<lightning-input type="text" label="OTP/PIN" onchange={handleOtpPINChange} data-id="otppin"></lightning-input>
JS
handleOtpPINChange(event){
    let OTPORPIN = ('' + String(event.deatil.value)).replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-id="otppin"]').value = OTPORPIN;
}
```

This happens instantly User will not see difference of removal of characters.